# Hide header and footer on an Application built on Xamarin, using WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, webview, hide

I've been building an application using Xamarin. I'm trying to connect my application to my webpage using WebView. The website menu appears on both the android and IOS application. I'm building in the portable (one code for android and iOS) solution. Is there a way to eliminate or hide the website menu.

This is my xaml.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace GoPriorV1.Views.ProgramViews
{
public partial class FirstToThird : ContentPage
{ 


public FirstToThird()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        browser.HeightRequest = 10000;
        browser.WidthRequest = 10000;
        browser.Source =  "https://goprior.com/prior6/content/robotics-elementary-students-1st-3rd";

        }

    void WebOnNavigating(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        status.Text = "Loading...";
    }

    void WebEndNavigating(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        status.Text = "Done!";
    }


    }
}
```

And this is my .xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="GoPriorV1.Views.ProgramViews.FirstToThird">

<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout>

        <!--Managing WebView-->
        <Label x:Name="status"/>
        <WebView x:Name="browser"                
                 Navigating="WebOnNavigating"
                 Navigated="WebEndNavigating"/>            
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

I created a JavaScript file, but I don't know how to call it or make it work in my project

```
var child_footers = document.getElementsByTagName("footer");


while (child_footers.length > 0) {
var footer_child = child_footers[0];
var footer_parent = footer_child.parentNode;
footer_parent.removeChild(footer_child);
}
```

Comment: The menu was defined by html file . So I'm not suggesting that you force the code to hide it.

Comment: I already create a costume native menu and I want to use the one I created.